# how to use rdkafka feature on laradock?

Tags: laravel, apache-kafka, laradock

I'm new with laradock and rdkafka, I have read documentaion laradock https://laradock.io/documentation, I already install like flow on section Install RDKAFKA extension*. But I don't know to use it, and I search on google there's no blog, website, etc about how to use this feature. Anyone can give me example to use kafka on laradock ??

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

just sudo docker-compose up --build -d zookeeper kafka